# Adding contents for the end of the document in the preamble

Tags: preamble

I create lots of LaTeX documents and put all my declarations into a `header.tex` that I use with `\input{header.tex}` at the beginning. However, I am migrated that into a `header.sty` and just use `\usepackage{header}` now.

Either way, my document always contains the same last lines that include a bibliography. I would like to move that into my `header.sty` as well. Is there some way to add end-of-document content into the preamble somehow?

The code that I have in mind is:

```
\IfFileExists{\bibliographyfile}{
    \printbibliography
}{}
```

The `\bibliographyfile` is defined in the preamble already.

Comment: `\AtEndDocument{your code}` should do, but this 'fixes' probably to the same bibliography?

Comment: It is just the `\printbibliography` of biblatex, so that does not really fix too much.

Comment: I am quite interested in this approach but not that experienced with latex - can you explain how you converted header.tex into header.sty? Or what resources you used to find out how!

Comment: I was browsing the Wikibook and found a section on [modular documents](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents#The_file_mystyle.sty). I thought it packages were more complex, but that paragraph was sufficient.

Comment: Fab, thanks. It does look very simple. Sorry I can't help, by the way!

Comment: @queueoverflow: I will try later on, if someone is faster than me... well, that's ok too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, the request was something in the following manner, loading everything automatically in the `header.sty` file.

Please change the `\DefaultBibliographyStyle` at will.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Not needed really


%%%% Content for `header.sty`
\newcommand*{\bibliographyfile}{biblio}%
\newcommand*{\DefaultBibliographyStyle}{alpha}%
\newcommand*{\DefaultBibFileExtension}{.bib}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\bibliographystyle{\DefaultBibliographyStyle}
\bibliography{\bibliographyfile}%
%
\IfFileExists{\bibliographyfile\DefaultBibFileExtension}{%
  \printbibliography%
}{}{}%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%% End stop copying it to the 'header.sty' file.


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\blindtext

\cite{Lam94} and \cite{GSM97} wrote fine books about \LaTeXe and other things.\par

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just tried it out, the `\AtEndDocument` does the trick.